About Arudino zero (ARMV6-M) assembly principle
I know that PC jumps can be implemented using the B, BL, and BX instructions, such as

B loop_start ; jump to the loop_start label,

or

BX LR ; return from a subroutine

But I also learned that PC jumps can also be realized using the MOV PC instruction, for example

MOV PC, R0 ;Jump to the address in R0

I want to know when the compiler generates the first B, BL, BX instructions? And when does it generate the MOV PC instruction?
I tried compiling the code, but I haven't encountered the use of the MOV instruction yet. However, in an ideal scenario, this should occur, right?

MOV PC, R0 would be used with a function pointer.  It will be more common in C++ code, with virtual functions and is used for interrupt returns on SOME ARM CPUs.

@artlessnoise Okay, thanks! I will give it a try.

since historically mov pc,r0 did not support switching modes (pre-cortex-m) the compilers are less likely to use that instruction and even if written or modified since bx r0 is more likely to happen.  If you are talking gnu or llvm then examine the compiler source itself and see if there is any case where it generates mov pc.   I would assume not.

hmmm that is interesting, see what you see and/or can generate.

Also quite possible that ldr pc, [rn, #xx] is used to call a virtual function.  You can see another form in this Q/A on ARM ldr pc as a transfer control mechanics.  I have seen compilers generate MOV PC, Rx before.  However, I think the ldr pc, [rn, #xx] will be more common.  As old timer eludes, 'interworking' and other thumb1-ish type options may completely kill mov pc, rn as generated by a compiler, as you need to OR the thumb bit (and there are other question on SO about this).
